# I have downloaded a android project. I want to run project in android studio, seeing followng screen

Tags: android, android-debug

**When I click on run**
[image: first screen when i chick run]

**when I click run, it can't run**

[image: screen when i click edit configure]

Comment: What happens when you click on run?

Comment: 2nd pic disappears and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

To run the project, you have to create a virtual device. As you are new to this, I recommend you to use a real device connected via USB cable. Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) for help. Feel free to comment if you are getting troubles.

**Update**

1. Click the plus button in the second screenshot you have provided.
2. Select "Android App"
3. Type "app" in Name box.
4. Apply

Comment: I have create virtual device, i have executed other projects normally, problem is with new downloaded project